# How to concat a number to another number when doing an insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concat a number to a max+1 number in an insert statement, but I'm a little stuck. My table goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `artcId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `artcUserId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `artcStackId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `artcPublicId` INT(10) ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `artcCountry` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artcTitle` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`artcUserId`, `artcId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

My current sql is like this:

```
insert into articles (artcUserId, artcStackId, artcCountry, artcTitle)
select 4,IFNULL((MAX(artcStackId)+1) ,0),'US','Hello World'
FROM articles;
```

What I'm tring to do is, concat a number to the new artcStackId and save it to the db. But i've got stuck. See the second image artcPublicId.

```
    insert into articles (artcUserId, artcStackId, artcCountry, artcTitle)
    select 2,IFNULL((MAX(artcStackId)+1) ,0),

    case when new.artcCountry = 'US' then conact(91, -- the new artcStackId goes here --)
         when new.artcCountry = 'UK' then conact(92, -- the new artcStackId goes here --)
         when new.artcCountry = 'CA' then conact(93, -- the new artcStackId goes here --)
    end

,'UK','Hello World'
FROM articles;
select * from articles;
```

Any idea how this can be done? artcPublicId is 91 or 92  or 93 depending on the country and the new artcStackId

[image: Current results]
[image: Desired results]

Comment: `IFNULL` can be replaced with `Coalesce` :) [Syntactic Sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Answer (score 0):

1. you may be better off making artcPublicId a varchar, which makes this easier to concat
2. if you know the number of digits places you would like to leave after 91/92/93 you could try something like

   (91 * 10000 + artcStackId)
3. you can convert to instring and back again, something like

   cast('910000' + cast(artcStackId as varchar), int(10))

Hope one of those helps

Comment: I created a trigger to do this. Do you see anything wrong with this?    SET new.artcPublicId=(
    case when new.artcCountry = 'US' then concat('91',new.artcStackId)
      when new.artcCountry = 'UK' then concat('92',new.artcStackId)
         when new.artcCountry = 'CA' then concat('93',new.artcStackId)
    end
)